# How to get group name using email or employee id?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I've a complete `DN` for example : `OU=Process,DC=SMS-PPO-1,DC=BOOKING,DC=COM`. I hope am correct that we call this path `dn` (`distinguished name`), correct me if am wrong.

Under this part, I've my all required groups and all of them starts from `ZZO`. (`groups in which I'm interested`)

I want to search using `empId`, that In which group (`starting from ZZO`) it falls.

May I know please, what kind of ldap query I can use to get this group name ?

Answer (score 0):

The complete path to an object in LDAP is indeed called the DN.
Typically, group memberships in LDAP are also DN values, pointing to the user that is a member, or reverse pointing to the group that the user is a member of. One limitation of DN values is that you cannot use wildcards while searching for those values.

When you want to find all groups that a specific user is a member of, there are 2 approaches:

1. Resolve the DN of the user object, and search from the base dn for groups starting with *ZZO* that have the user DN listed as a member
2. Read the group memberships (a list of DNs) of the user and filter out the groups starting with *ZZO*

### 1: Search for groups

You can resolve the user DN by searching for the user using the empID (assumption: `(CN=empId)`) and saving the returned object DN in a variable, e.g. `userDn`.

In your case, `OU=Process,DC=SMS-PPO-1,DC=BOOKING,DC=COM` is the so-called *base DN* where your search starts.

You can then search for groups from the base dn with this LDAP filter:

```
(&(CN=ZZO*)(member=userDn))
```

Obviously, you need to perform 2 searches in this case.

### 2: Read the user object

When you search for the user object you can tell the server to return the groups that the user is a member of. My assumption is that you `empId` value is the user's CN *attribute* (== field in LDAP). If that is not the case, you need to find out which attribute it is.

Then, perform a search for `(attribute=empId)` and tell the server to return the `memberOf` attribute.

The returned values for `memberOf` will contain group DN values. Filter out the groups that have a DN of the format `CN=ZZO*,OU=Process,DC=SMS-PPO-1,DC=BOOKING,DC=COM` and you have your list.

---

Simply put: if you are only interested in a list of group DNs, then option 2 is the easiest and most efficient. However if you need to retrieve more data from those groups, scenario 1 gives you a list of group objects to work with.

Of course the technical details depend on the language that you are using. Good luck!